# Resize Composable height to be the same as width

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to implement a grid UI with 2 columns in Jetpack Compose.

My requirements are

- Width of each item must be half the parent width (minus padding .etc.)
- Height must be the same so the item is a square.
- Inside this I should be able to do other things like use `weight` in a `Column`

This should look as below

```
<-- parent 
    width -->
 ____   ____
|    | |    |
|____| |____|

 ____   ____
|    | |    |
|____| |____|

 ... and more items
```

I have part way achieved this with the code below, however the height doesn't appear to be "sent" to the children.

```
// can use this inside a Column or LazyColumn
@Composable
fun TileRow() {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, fill = true).padding(10.dp)) {
            TestTile()
        }

        Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, fill = true).padding(10.dp)) {
               TestTile()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TestTile (){
    Surface(
            color = Color.Red,
            modifier = Modifier
                    .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                        val placeable = measurable.measure((constraints))
                        //placeable.height = placeable.width // can't resize. height has a private setter
                        layout(placeable.width, placeable.width) {
                            placeable.place(x = 0, y = 0, zIndex = 0f)
                    }
            }.fillMaxSize() // fills the width, but not height, likely due to above layout
    ){
        Column {
            Text(text = "item1")
            Text(text = "item2 to fill",
                    modifier = Modifier
                            .weight(1f)) // this is gone when weight is added
            Text(text = "item3")
        }
    }
}
```

This creates the following UI instead.

[image: current output for code]

It appears the `Surface` laid out correctly, since the next `Row` has space. But the column appears to not take the full height. This also means the `weight()` for column items doesn't work. Adding the `weight` modifier to column children makes them just disappear.

How can I fix the above so the children can know the height and achieve the intended result?

For reference I'm using Jetpack Compose `alpha09`

**UPDATE:** I have tried using the `preferredHeight(IntrinsicSize.Max)` and it seems to work better, but it does require making the code be marked with `@ExperimentalLayout` so prefer not to use it yet if there's another option available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the constraints for your tile yourself, based on the width of the TileRow:

```
layout { measurable, constraints ->
                val tileSize = constraints.maxWidth / columnCount

                val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints.copy(
                    minWidth = tileSize,
                    maxWidth = tileSize,
                    minHeight = tileSize,
                    maxHeight = tileSize,
                ))

                layout(placeable.width, placeable.width) {
                    placeable.place(x = 0, y = 0, zIndex = 0f)
                }
}
```

See [LazyGrid](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyGrid.kt;bpv=0) for a complete example